# When editing specific data, that specific data is not loaded for editing

Tags: javascript, frontend

When editing specific data, that specific data is not loaded for editing. This is the code of the edit file. I used frontend technology as React js and Backend technology as Koa js. Here I used mongo DB as a Database. This code does not work correctly for editing. Is there any issue with the code?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/student/${id}").then((res) => {
      setStudent(res.data.existingData);
      setName(res.data.existingData.name);
      setAge(res.data.existingData.age);
      setCity(res.data.existingData.city);
    });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use backticks to define a URL

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/student/${id}`).then((res) => {
```